# AWS Amplify GraphQL fetch data using multiple input parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, next.js, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I'm working on Next.js and I have this setup:

```
const data = await API.graphql({
  query: projectByUserIdandProjectId,
  variables: {
    userId: props.userId,
    projectId: project.id,
  },
});
```

Then I have this schema:

```
type Project
  @model
  @key(
    name: "byUserId"
    fields: ["userId"]
    queryField: "projectByUserIdandProjectId"
  )
  id: ID!
  userId: ID!
  projectId: ID!
}
```

I tried adding projectId into fields: `fields: ["userId", "projectId"]` but when I was looking at amplify's queries console, it doesn't give me an option to add the projectId.

I wanted to be able to get 1 data from the record when both userId and projectId matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why adding `projectId` again in the Project model when you can use `id`?

I don't know about your use case, but you can use `filter`.

```
type Project
  @model
  @key(
    name: "byUserId"
    fields: ["userId"]
    queryField: "projectByUserId"
  )
  id: ID!
  userId: ID!
  projectId: ID!
}
```

```
import { API, graphqlOperation } from "aws-amplify";

--- 

await API.graphql(
  graphqlOperation(projectByUserId, {
    userId: props.userId,
    filter: { projectId: { eq: props.projectId } }
  })
);
```